# clang: error: the clang compiler does not support '-mfpu=neon-vfpv4'

Tags: android, clang

while compiling Android JB, I'm getting clang errors

```
clang: error: the clang compiler does not support '-mfpu=neon-vfpv4'
```

any help on how to fix this.

Comment: ... don't pass that flag?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this quick fix.

Comment: you have to use `-mfloat-abi=softfp` or `-mfloat-abi=hard` with `-mfpu`